# AJAX and Jinja2

Tags: jquery, jinja2

I want to use an AJAX call with parameters within a Jinja2 template. But how do I make it possible? I want to do something like this.

JavaScript:

```javascript
$.get("test.html", { name: "John", time: "2pm" } );
```

jinja template:

```html
<div>
{{name}} {{time}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to access the request object on the server side to get the arguments. I'm assuming you're using Flask, but if not, the basic idea should be the same on other web frameworks as well. Let's say you have a simple little index.html, where you use Javascript to make your Ajax query:

```
$.get("{{ url_for('ajax') }}", {name: "John", time: "2pm"});
```

Note that if you're not using Jinja2 to render the script portion, replace the url_for()-call with the actual URL, so something like /ajax in my example further below:

```
$.get("/ajax", {name: "John", time: "2pm"});
```

Now, on the server side you would have something like this:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/ajax')
def ajax():

    #Access arguments via request.args
    name = request.args.get('name')
    time = request.args.get('time')

    #NOTE: In real code, check that the arguments exist

    #Silly logging call to show that arguments are there
    app.logger.info(name)
    app.logger.info(time)

    #Do stuff here to do what you want or modify name/time
    ...

    #Render template and pass the arguments to it
    return render_template('ajax.html',
                           name=name,
                           time=time)

@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

and ajax.html would look something like this for example:

```
<h2>{{ name }}</h2>
<h2>{{ time }}</h2>
```

So request.args is where you can access the arguments you've passed with GET, but you need to pass them explicitly to Jinja2 with the render_template() call. Jinja2 is just a templating language and it is not aware of your arguments (1) unless you pass them to it.

1) With some exceptions. Flask for example does pass a few arguments to Jinja2 implicitly, like the request object.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I found out all i needed was this cxt['myParam'] = req.args and I could do {{myParam}} in the template. The format I get is {'name': ['John'], 'time': ['2pm']}. How do I decode it so I can use it in a condition. {% if myParam.name == 'John'%}

Comment: I think I got it now. I am using {{myParam.name[0]}} for example

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery to get the contents of the div. To make it easy use element selectors :

```
<div>
    <span id="name">{{name}}</span> <span id="time">{{time}}</span>
</div>


name = $("#name").text()
time = $("#time").text()
$.get("test.html", {name : name, time : time} );
```

Comment: No what I want to do is sent the name and time to the server as parameters. So I can do something like if name == 'John' { do some code }

Comment: The data is send like : { name: "John", time: "2pm" }

Comment: But how do I write out the name and time on the server? If I type {{name}} or {{time}} I get   <span>jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError</span>: <span>'name' is undefined</span>

Comment: {% extends 'layout.html' %} <div>{{name}}</div> it's jinja2

Comment: You showed your template. But you have to show your handler code, because I assume something is wrong with the template context (name is undefined).

Comment: Have a look at the getting started example: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/templates